# Infinite animation create with keyframes CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPOXQR)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<img src="https://i1.wp.com/img.celmaitare.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Poze-Peisaje-179.jpg" class="img">
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
@keyframes fade-img {
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0.5;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease;
    }
}

.img{
  animation-name: fade-bg;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

I want to repeat this animation after 2 seconds but it does not understand why it does not work.

Can you please tell me what is wrong?
Is it a syntax mistake?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo.  The animation is called `.fade-img` not `.fade-bg`.  See the code snippet below. A little extra something: you can add `animation-direction: alternate;` to make the image fade both in and out smoothly.

```css
@keyframes fade-img {
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  }
}

.img{
  max-width: 100%;
  animation-name: fade-img;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease;
       -o-transition: all 0.9s ease;
          transition: all 0.9s ease;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i1.wp.com/img.celmaitare.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Poze-Peisaje-179.jpg" class="img">
```

`

Comment: You have keen eyes;-)

Comment: Thank you! This was one of the few times I wasn't beaten to the punch :D